# MongdDB replica set on docker compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongodb-replica-set

I have the following docker compose file:

```
services:
  mongodb-primary:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4-debian-10'
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
    volumes:
      - 'mongodb_master_data:/bitnami/mongodb'
    ports:
      - 30001:27017

  mongodb-secondary:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4-debian-10'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
    ports:
      - 30002:27017

  mongodb-arbiter:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4-debian-10'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-arbiter
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=arbiter
      - MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-primary
      - MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
    ports:
      - 30003:27017

volumes:
  mongodb_master_data:
    driver: local
```

Now, when I try to connect from Robo 3T in the direct connection mode with localhost:30001, root:password123 I am able to do that.

Unfortunatelly when I want to connect by using replica set connectionstring I cannot do that.

This is my connectionstring:

`mongodb://root:password123@localhost:30001,localhost:30002/admin?replicaSet=myRepl`

TLS is disabled,

What can I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To run a mongodb cluster, you need to also run `mongos` routers and mongodb config servers.

Something like:

- 2 `mongos` routers
- 3 `mongodb` config servers (don't run with 2 and don't run an aribter)
- 3 `mongodb` replica servers in PSA (Primary, Secondary, Arbiter)

And you would connect to the `mongos` routers, not the individual db servers.